# Eclipse runtime error

Tags: java, eclipse

I just restarted my Eclipse and now when I try to run my project via *run configuration* it is showing this error:

```
Referenced classpath provider does not exist: org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.classpathProvider
```

Any ideas what the problem is?

Thanks,

Comment: Create a new run configuration.

Comment: are you moved from eclipse to another Eclipse version ?

Comment: Delete the Run Configuration for that project and re create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It’s probably because your Run Configuration was created on an old project, and has bad entries in the Classpath section. The solution is to delete the Run Configuration and create a new one.

[I read here](http://sha.nnoncarey.com/blog/archives/33)